# Why is my $parent binding context empty inside a Knockout.js foreach template?

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm calling the following template through Knockout:

```
<script type="text/html" id="uploaded-files-template">
    <li data-bind="text: original_name"></li>
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($parent, null, 2)"></pre>
</script>
```

which is being called in a foreach loop from this:

```
<ul class="files-list" data-bind="template: { name: 'uploaded-files-template', foreach: uploadedFiles, as: 'uploadedFile' }"></ul>
```

I'm trying to access the `$parent` binding context from my template, but I'm being told it is `undefined`, and when I try and output it JSON-formatted (as I am doing above), it is empty.

`$uploadedFiles` is a `ko.observableArray()`:

```
self.uploadedFiles = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Which is populated via AJAX like so:

[image]

and then pushed on:

```
$.each(message.objects, function(index, object) {
    self.uploadedFiles.push(object);
});
```

If I replace `$parent` with `$data`, I can see the current iteration being outputted. Any idea why this `$parent` does not show anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your templates and bindings, see working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysnuky9n/).

```
var SimpleListModel = function(items) {
    this.uploadedFiles = ko.observableArray(items);    
};

var model = new SimpleListModel([
    { original_name: "One" }, 
    { original_name: "Two" },
    { original_name: "Three" }]
)

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

It has to be mistake in your viewModel or viewModel population.

Comment: *perfect ! your are right there must be something wrong in vm .

Comment: I'm not seeing any differences in my VM, apart from you passing an `items` parameter to your VM which you have and I cannot do. I have declared my `uploadedFiles` observable array in my VM and populated it within my VM.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/ysnuky9n/1/ that should work too .

Comment: @supercool, I have absolutely no idea why this is working for you but not for me. To populate the array, I am pushing the objects on, but that should not make a difference, surely...

Comment: Well, I found the answer. Check mine below. Thanks for the help all.

Comment: yes there is no difference . it works as usual if i push into observableArray check this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/ysnuky9n/2/

Answer (score 1):

Err... well, this is embarrassing. My `$parent` context was empty simply because I was not instantiating my ViewModel. I was doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(uploadViewModel);
});
```

When I should have been doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new uploadViewModel());
});
```

Thanks to Max Brodin & supercool for helping out, however.